# How to instantiate an inner class with reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, instantiationexception

I try to instantiate the inner class defined in the following Java code:

```
 public class Mother {
      public class Child {
          public void doStuff() {
              // ...
          }
      }
 }
```

When I try to get an instance of Child like this

```
 Class<?> clazz= Class.forName("com.mycompany.Mother$Child");
 Child c = clazz.newInstance();
```

I get this exception:

```
 java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mycompany.Mother$Child
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    ...
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Uhm, your inner class is not static... Is this on purpose? Coming from a C# background maybe? ;)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting "static" idea! In fact, using a static nested class instead of an inner class make my life easier.

Comment: The thing is, if an inner class is not declared static, instances of this class depend on the existence of an instance of the outer class; this is different from C# where all inner classes are "static" by default, and can be instantiated without a parent instance.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There's an extra "hidden" parameter, which is the instance of the enclosing class. You'll need to get at the constructor using [`Class.getDeclaredConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and then supply an instance of the enclosing class as an argument. For example:

```
// All exception handling omitted!
Class<?> enclosingClass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.Mother");
Object enclosingInstance = enclosingClass.newInstance();

Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("com.mycompany.Mother$Child");
Constructor<?> ctor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(enclosingClass);

Object innerInstance = ctor.newInstance(enclosingInstance);
```

Alternatively, if the nested class doesn't actually need to refer to an enclosing instance, make it a nested *static* class instead:

```
public class Mother {
     public static class Child {
          public void doStuff() {
              // ...
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Just an extra is that if the inner class isn't public, you need to call `ctor.setAccessible(true)` in order to make it work!

Comment: Funny, while walking my dog I thought ... it is so strange, Jon has so many answers, but I rarely run into them when I lookup things. And then ... working on some answer of mine ... I did. And your answer helped me answer some tricky thingy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984297/is-there-any-way-to-instantiate-a-class-defined-in-anonymous-inner-class/ Thanks!

Comment: so now you have the inner instance how would you call a method of it?

Comment: @Oxnard: That's really not part of this question. You can just call a method as normal, but if you're having problems, ask a new question.

Answer (score -3):

This code create inner class instance.

```
  Class childClass = Child.class;
  String motherClassName = childClass.getCanonicalName().subSequence(0, childClass.getCanonicalName().length() - childClass.getSimpleName().length() - 1).toString();
  Class motherClassType = Class.forName(motherClassName) ;
  Mother mother = motherClassType.newInstance()
  Child child = childClass.getConstructor(new Class[]{motherClassType}).newInstance(new Object[]{mother});
```