# Java - Pass private class to a method

Tags: java, exception, reflection, parameters, constructor

So I have a neat little function which I can use to construct objects when my functions don't know what classes they'll be dealing with. (Yes I do have some nice uses for this before Soritos or anyone else wants to tell me I'm illogical)

```
public static Object Construct(Class type, Class[] params, Object[] values){
    //Create an object of any class
    try{
       Constructor con = type.getConstructor(params);
       Object o = con.newInstance(values);
       return o;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR EXCEPTION"); 
       return null;
    }
}
```

Anyway I have a class declared within another class file that I want the main class to be able to pass to this function.

```
public class aClass {
   public aClass(String S, String s){
      Class c = otherClass.class;
      Object o = Functions.Construct(c, new Class[]{String.class, String.class}, new Object[]{S, s});
   }    
}

class otherClass{   
    public otherClass(String arg1, String arg2){}
}
```

But with this I get an exception. Is this because otherClass is not visible to my constructor function outside of this class?

Comment: Aside from any comment on the Rube-Goldberg quality of this code, you probably want to post your stack trace first.

Comment: What's funny about my code? It's a simplified example of my problem. 
Well that's the thing it's catching the exception so I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: Use a debugger? Use proper `Exception` handling instead of your suppression? There's little to answer here unless you post the whole problem, not just some code dump.

Comment: No exceptions for me! Code executed successfully.

Comment: This is the whole problem, stop being obnoxious. I'll find a way to get information about the Exception. 
Seeing as it's still throwing an exception at this simplified level however it works perfectly for public classes I thought this might be something obvious for an experienced java programmer.

Comment: Someone posted an answer that worked but deleted it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485297/java-how-to-instantiate-inner-class-with-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Functions` and `aClass` (assuming `otherClass` is in the same file as `aClass`) are in the same package, your code does not raise any exception. ITOH, if these 2 classes are not in the same package, there is an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class pack1.Functions can not access a member of class pack2.otherClass with modifiers "public"
```

The constructor of `otherClass` is `public` and is found by reflection, but the class itself has *package private* visibility. That's why `Functions#Construct(...)` cannot instantiate it.

If you really want to instantiate through reflection package private classes, you can bypass the access security check with `setAccessibility(true)` as described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) and suggested by @Anuj

> A value of true indicates that the reflected object should suppress Java language access checking when it is used.

```
public static Object Construct(Class type, Class[] params, Object[] values){
    //Create an object of any class
    try{
       Constructor con = type.getConstructor(params);
       con.setAccessible(true);
       Object o = con.newInstance(values);
       return o;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR EXCEPTION"); 
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realise these things were by-passable

Answer (score 1):

If your context doesn't use a security manager you can try making the constructor accessible by reflection.

```
con.setAccessible(true);
```