# No empty constructor error when trying to instantiate class object by name

Tags: android, constructor

There are several related questions on StackOverflow, but none seem to solve my problem.

Consider the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // ...


    private class MyClass {

        protected void myMethod() {
                // ...
                MyExtendedClass var = (MyExtendedClass)Class.forName("com.example.myapp.MainActivity$MyExtendedClass").newInstance();
                // ...
        }
    }

    private class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass {
        // ...
    }   
}
```

When the line initializing `var` is called, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.myapp.MainActivity$MyExtendedClass; no empty constructor
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Even if I add the following constructors to their corresponding classes, I still get the same error:

```
public MyClass() {
    // nothing
}

public MyExtendedClass() {
    super();
}
```

Comment: java's basics: inner non static class http://ideone.com/Sx9I3q

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post[instance inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485297/how-to-instantiate-inner-class-with-reflection-in-java) 
and here is some modify to work with your case:

```
Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName(MainActivity.class.getName() + "$MyExtendedClass");
                    Constructor<?> ctor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(MainActivity.class);
                    ctor.setAccessible(true);
                    MyExtendedClass var = (MyExtendedClass)ctor.newInstance(MainActivity.this);
```