# InstantiationException when using a generic java class

Tags: java, generics, instantiationexception

I would like to create a simulation containing an entity. There can be two kinds of entities, complex and simple ones. When I instantiate a simple simulation, I want the simple entity to be instantiated, and when I instantiate a complex simulation I want the complex entity to be instantiated.

**Entities:**

```
class ComplexEntity extends Entity {
    public ComplexEntity(){}
}

class SimpleEntity extends Entity  {
    public SimpleEntity(){}
}

class Entity {
    public Entity(){}
}
```

**Simulations:**

```
class ComplexSimulation extends Simulation<ComplexEntity>
{

    public ComplexSimulation() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        super(ComplexEntity.class);
    }

}

class SimpleSimulation extends Simulation<SimpleEntity>
{
    public SimpleSimulation() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        super(SimpleEntity.class);
    }
}

class Simulation<E extends Entity> {
    protected final E entity;

    public Simulation(Class<E> class1) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException 
    {
        entity = class1.newInstance();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to construct a ComplexSimulation:

```
ComplexSimulation c = new ComplexSimulation();
```

I get the following InstantiationException:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: test.Test$ComplexEntity
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at test.Test$Simulation.<init>(Test.java:55)
at test.Test$ComplexSimulation.<init>(Test.java:37)
at test.Test.go(Test.java:12)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.Test$ComplexEntity.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
```

The zero argument constructor cannot be the problem because my entities have them... Does anybody know what the problem can be?

Comment: The exception should be telling you what is wrong. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Comment: You are using a generic class without erasure, the generic type doesn't now the actual type.

Comment: The problem is that you're using inner classes. Move each class into a proper top class or mark them static.

Comment: Are all those classes inner classes?

Comment: Yes they are! I made this test code in a single class, I'll try it again using multiple classes.

Comment: It's working now, thanks  Luiggi Mendoza and  Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using inner classes. You cannot create an instance of an inner class without an instance of the outer class, not even if you call `Class<InnerClass>.newInstance()`.

Just make these inner classes to be top classes and your example should work as expected.

If you really want/need to initialize non-static inner classes using reflection, see here: [How to instantiate inner class with reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17485297/1065197)

Comment: this is also not the case

Comment: Yes it is the case nikpon! Thanks Luiggi, your solution solved my problem.

Comment: @nikpon yes it is. Just look at the stacktrace.

Comment: It there a way to make invoking `newInstance()` (or similar), on an inner class work?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, this is covered in other Q/A so I've posted the link here in my answer.