# I can`t create an instance of nested classes and can't initialize the fields. I want to pass the Unit test

Tags: java, reflection, junit

I get the class type of the nested classes in debug mode, but I can' t create an instance to initialize in the next step the Fields of the nested instance. (See my comented lines). So my Unit test fails with Error.

```
public class Reflector {
public static <T> T initialize(Class<? extends T> clazz) {

    try {
        Object classInstance = clazz.newInstance();
        System.out.println("MainclassInstance: "+ classInstance.toString());

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

            System.out.println(
             "\n### 1. For-Schleife\nclazz.getDeclaredFields().size(): " + clazz.getDeclaredFields().length);

            System.out.println("clazz.field: " + field.getName());

            //Class Object
            if (field.getType().isMemberClass()) {

                Object memberClassInstance = field.getType();      //Nested$FirstNested

                System.out.println("memberClassInstance: " + memberClassInstance.toString()); //Nested$FirstNested

                List<Field> memberClassFields = Arrays.asList(((Class<?>) memberClassInstance).getDeclaredFields());

                for (int memberFieldIndex = 0; memberFieldIndex < memberClassFields.size() - 1; memberFieldIndex++) {
                    System.out.println("meberClassField: " + memberClassFields.get(memberFieldIndex).getName());


                    //memberClassFields.get(memberFieldIndex).set(memberClassInstance, "nestedField");
                }
                //field.set(memberClassInstance, "MyObject");
                //field.set(classInstance, memberClassInstance);
            }

        }

        return (T) classInstance;

    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is the JUnit test class

```
public class ReflectorTest {

    @Test
    public void testInitializeNestedObject() {
        Nested actual = Reflector.initialize(Nested.class);

        assertNotNull(actual);
        assertNotNull(actual.nested1);
        assertTrue(actual.nested1 instanceof Nested.FirstNested);
        assertNotNull(actual.nested1.nestedField1);
        assertNotNull(actual.nested1.nestedField2);

        assertNotNull(actual.nested2);
        assertTrue(actual.nested2 instanceof Nested.SecondNested);
        assertNotNull(actual.nested2.nestedField3);
        assertNotNull(actual.nested2.nestedField4);
    }
}
```

This is the class for data

```
public class Nested {

    public class FirstNested{
        public Object nestedField1;
        public Object nestedField2;
    }

    public class SecondNested{
        public Object nestedField3;
        public Object nestedField4;
    }

    public FirstNested nested1;
    public SecondNested nested2;

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `memberClassInstance` is not declared anywere.

Comment: please insert the following line after the if-case in the class Reflactor:                                                                                      **Object memberClassInstance = field.getType();      //Nested$FirstNested**

Comment: Just update your original post, so everyone can see the correct version

Comment: My Code is updated. This is my first article. Im a newbie in this forum :-)

Comment: No worries. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you create instance for the container class `Nested` you don't create instances for the enclosed classes `FirstNested` and `SecondNested`. In order to make these kind of instances you can change your class like this

```
public static class Nested
{
    public static class FirstNested
    {
        public Object nestedField1;
        public Object nestedField2;
    }

    public static class SecondNested
    {
        public Object nestedField3;
        public Object nestedField4;
    }

    public FirstNested nested1;
    public SecondNested nested2;

}
```

You have to make the inner classes static so they can be accessed easily by reflection. Then you have to implement (maybe in a recursive way) the creation of new instances and registering those instances to your container class instance.

Something like this

```
Object memberClassInstance = field.getType().newInstance();
field.set(classInstance, memberClassInstance);
```

Or you can keep the classes as they are and use something like this

```
Object memberClassInstance = field.getType().getConstructor(Nested.class).newInstance()
```

As @CoronA mentions in the comments. More on how to instantiate inner classes can be found here [How to instantiate inner class with reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485297/how-to-instantiate-inner-class-with-reflection-in-java)

Comment: Strictly - there is no need to change the inner classes to static ones. With non-static nested inner classes you lower statement would look like (!) `Object memberClassInstance = field.getType().getConstructor(Nested.class).newInstance()` (nested classes constructors add the outer class to their arguments).

Comment: I deserved a down vote for that one. Thanks for giving me the chance to correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution:

```
public class Reflector {
public static <T> T initialize(Class<? extends T> clazz) {

    try {
        Object classInstance = clazz.newInstance();
        System.out.println("MainclassInstance: " + classInstance.toString());

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {

            System.out.println(
                    "\n### 1. For-Schleife\nclazz.getDeclaredFields().size(): "
                    + clazz.getDeclaredFields().length);

            System.out.println("clazz.field: " + field.getName());


            //Class Object
            if (field.getType().isMemberClass()) {


                Object innerInstance = null;
                try {

                    Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName(field.getType().getName());
                    Constructor<?> ctor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(classInstance.getClass());
                    innerInstance = ctor.newInstance(classInstance);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                //###############
                Object memberClassInstance = field.getType();      //Nested$FirstNested

                System.out.println("memberClassInstance: " + memberClassInstance.toString()); //Nested$FirstNested

                List<Field> memberClassFields = Arrays.asList((innerInstance.getClass()).getDeclaredFields());

                for (int memberFieldIndex = 0; memberFieldIndex < memberClassFields.size() - 1; memberFieldIndex++) {
                    System.out.println("meberClassField: " + memberClassFields.get(memberFieldIndex).getName());
                    memberClassFields.get(memberFieldIndex).set(innerInstance, memberClassFields.get(memberFieldIndex).getName() + (memberFieldIndex+1));     
                }

                field.set(classInstance,innerInstance);

            }

        }

        return (T) classInstance;

    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reflector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```