# Runnables Instantiation Java

Tags: java, java-8, strategy-pattern

I am trying to write an `ExecutorService` as in `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` with a runnable given as a parameter to method filling the `ThreadPool`.

this is not about instantiating a inner class like proposed here [How to instantiate inner class with reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485297/how-to-instantiate-inner-class-with-reflection-in-java) I actually want an alternative on using reflections.

The `Runnable` to be run by the thread pool is an instance of an abstract runner. I can't create an instance with `testRunnable.newInstance()` nor with `testRunnable::new` because of an error caused by:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ...$MyRunner.() exception.

For now I am doing this via reflections:

```
public void doStuff() throws Exception {
        MyRunner r = new MyRunner();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            doMoreStuff(r.getClass(), this);
        }
    }

    public void doMoreStuff(Class<? extends TestRunner> clazz, Object... params) throws Exception {
        Class<?>[] types = Stream.of(params).map(Object::getClass).toArray(n -> new Class[n]);
        TestRunner t = clazz.getConstructor(types).newInstance(params);
        new Thread(t).start();
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the reason you are not just passing it the runnable instances, creating them in `doStuff()` instead of in `doMoreStuff()`?

Comment: You are not using a ThreadPool here but are executing raw thread. I'm not sure what the first part of question is about?

Comment: And I don't understand why you're using reflection.

Comment: When you use an interface or an abstract class to decouple classes, you should also use the [Inversion of Control principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) described by @RealSkeptic. Otherwise, you can directly create an instance of the concrete class (stored in a reference of type of that concrete class) and you have not won anything.

Comment: I am using, a threadPool, but left this out for the example here, to reduce the code to the crux of the problem.

Comment: thanks for the good questions. I want to reduce duplicate code by passing different specialisations of the runnable to the 'doMoreStuff()' method to be run for example in a thread pool, for instance doing measuring of its execution time or similar.  I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear, what you actually want to do. If you want to do the same as in your question but without Reflection, you can simply do it as

```
public void doStuff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        doMoreStuff(new MyRunner());
    }
}

public void doMoreStuff(TestRunner t) {
    new Thread(t).start();
}
```

as that’s what you are actually doing in your question’s code and it also matches what you have written in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921285/runnables-instantiation-java#comment55604438_33921285): “I want to reduce duplicate code by passing different specializations of the runnable to the `doMoreStuff()` method”. You can pass arbitrary specializations of `TestRunner` to the method `doMoreStuff`…

---

It seems you want to perform the creation of new instances within the method `doMoreStuff()` rather than at the caller though your question does not provide any hint about *why*. If there’s a justified reason, you can do it like:

```
public void doStuff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        doMoreStuff(MyRunner::new);
    }
}

public void doMoreStuff(Supplier<? extends TestRunner> s) {
    new Thread(s.get()).start();
}
```

though it would be more natural to do something like:

```
public void doStuff() {
    doMoreStuff(MyRunner::new);
}

public void doMoreStuff(Supplier<? extends TestRunner> s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new Thread(s.get()).start();
}
```

which is indeed separating the “ten times” execution strategy and the decision which implementation to execute.

---

If your problem stems from an attempt to allow the outer instance to be provided as a parameter, that doesn’t work with `::new` method references as these always treat the outer instance as implied and pre-bound. You have to resort to a lambda expression in this case:

```
public void doStuff() {
    doMoreStuff(outer -> outer.new MyRunner(), this);
}

public <T> void doMoreStuff(Function<T,? extends TestRunner> s, T context) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        new Thread(s.apply(context)).start();
}
```