# Creat inner static class instance by its name

Tags: java, instance, inner-classes

I need to create instances from each statically defined inner classes, but I get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**.

First, I collect the declared inner classes:

```
public String[] getInnerClassNames(Class<?> p_class) {
    Class<?>[] declaredClasses = p_class.getDeclaredClasses();
    String[] innerClassNames = new String[declaredClasses.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < declaredClasses.length; i++) {
        innerClassNames[i] = declaredClasses[i].getCanonicalName();
    }
    return innerClassNames;
}
```

where the **p_class** is the outer class.

Second,  I do the class loading and instantiation for the given inner class name:

```
public Object createObjectByClassName(String p_className)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(p_className);
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

This inner class name has the form: **PACKAGE**.**OUTER_CLASS_NAME**.**INNER_CLASS_NAME**.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instantiate an inner class with reflection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485297/how-to-instantiate-an-inner-class-with-reflection-in-java)

Comment: @Oleg I think that answers the obvious follow up question rather than the original.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Alright, retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `Class.getName`.

`Class.getCanonicalName` will return the name according to the Java Language Specification. You want the name that the JVM/bytecode is using.

The names differ because the JVM roughly matches the Java 1.0 language. The approach made to compatibility makes everything new look like a bit of a hack at the bytecode level.

Also, the constructor may well be different, as the inner class requires a reference to its context.

Comment: *"the name according to the Java Language Specification"* - this is misleading; all kinds of names in Java are "according to the JLS", because the JLS defines the language. What you're referring to is the *binary name*, as opposed to the *simple name* or the *canonical name*.